# string iterator not stopping at end of string

Tags: c++, string, loops, iterator, segmentation-fault

I'm reading yummy recipes from a line made of different substrings divided by `;` in this order:

- Recipe index (`R1`)
- Number to be cooked (`1`)
- Recipe name (`Ensalada Mixta`)
- Ingredients and their quantity (`Lechuga 200;...`)

The first three work like a charm, you can see they are stored in the `data` array and printed in the `printf` block. The problem comes reading the rest. The `reader` iterator reads through the line perfectly but doesn't stop at the end, so it add rubbish values to the pair and throws a segfault. Here's the output from this MRE:

```
:: R1
:: 1
:: Ensalada Mixta
-> Lechuga 200
-> Tomate 50
-> Pepino 50
-> Cebolla 50
-> Aceite Oliva 5
-> Vinagre De Vino 10
-> Sal 1
[1]    85313 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The loop should stop after `Sal 1`, so what am I doing terribly wrong? Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string line = "R1;1;Ensalada Mixta;Lechuga 200;Tomate 50;Pepino 50;Cebolla 50;Aceite Oliva 5;Vinagre De Vino 10;Sal 1";
    list<pair<string, unsigned> > ings;

    string recipe_data[3];
    string::const_iterator reader = line.cbegin();

    //Lectura del código, plato y ing_name de la receta
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++reader) {
        if (*reader != ';')
            recipe_data[i].push_back(*reader);
        else
            ++i;
    }

    printf(":: %s\n", recipe_data[0].c_str());
    printf(":: %s\n", recipe_data[1].c_str());
    printf(":: %s\n", recipe_data[2].c_str());
/*
 * This is the problematic loop. The problem is in the while boolean
 * expression, which always evaluates to false.
 */
    while (reader != line.cend()) {
        string ing_name = "";
        unsigned ing_quantity = 0;

        while (*reader != ';' && reader != line.cend()) {
            ing_name += *reader;
            ++reader;
        }

        string::reverse_iterator it = ing_name.rbegin();

        for (int i = 0; *it != ' '; i++) {
            char c[1] = {*it};
            ing_quantity += atoi(c) * pow(10, i);
            ++it;
            ing_name.pop_back();
        }
        ing_name.pop_back();

        pair<string, unsigned> ing(ing_name, ing_quantity);
        ings.push_back(ing);

        printf("-> %s %d\n", ing.first.c_str(), ing.second);

        ++reader;
    }
}
```

Here's gdb output using a breakpoint on the very last `++reader` line:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at so.cpp:52
52          ++reader;
1: reader = 59 ';'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Tomate", second = 50}
(gdb) 
Continuing.
-> Pepino 50

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.cpp:52
52          ++reader;
1: reader = 59 ';'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Pepino", second = 50}
(gdb) 
Continuing.
-> Cebolla 50

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.cpp:52
52          ++reader;
1: reader = 59 ';'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Cebolla", second = 50}
(gdb) 
Continuing.
-> Aceite Oliva 5

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.cpp:52
52          ++reader;
1: reader = 59 ';'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Aceite Oliva", second = 5}
(gdb) 
Continuing.
-> Vinagre De Vino 10

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.cpp:52
52          ++reader;
1: reader = 59 ';'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Vinagre De Vino", second = 10}
(gdb) 
Continuing.
-> Sal 1

Breakpoint 1, main () at so.cpp:52
52          ++reader;
1: reader = 0 '\000'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Sal", second = 1}
(gdb) n
47          pair<string, unsigned> ing(ing_name, ing_quantity);
1: reader = 0 '\000'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Sal", second = 1}
(gdb) 
29          string ing_name = "";
1: reader = 0 '\000'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Sal", second = 1}
(gdb) 
28      while (reader != line.cend()) {
1: reader = 0 '\000'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
(gdb) 
29          string ing_name = "";
1: reader = 0 '\000'
2: line.cend() = 0 '\000'
3: ing = {first = "Sal", second = 1}
```

As you can see, it shouldn't have re-entered the loop since the iterator and `cend()` are equal, right?

Comment: When `reader` becomes `line.cend()`, the shown code will still `*reader != ';'` first, before comparing `reader` to `line.cend()`. This derefences the ending iterator, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed an error, but fixing it doens't get rid of the segfault because it comes from the previous comparison too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner while increments until either you find `;` or `cend` and in both cases you continue. Only on the next iteration you stop because `reader != line.cend()` is `false` but thats already too late.

Also you have to first check if you are at the end, and only then dereference `reader`:

```
    while (reader != line.cend() && *reader != ';') {
        ing_name += *reader;
        ++reader;
    }
    if (reader == line.cend()) break;
```

Comment: I must have missed something terribly important in my classes, because logic tells me that it we break when `reader == line.cend()`, we don't enter the loop when `reader != line.cend()`. How does dereferencing the iterator affect the comparison?

Comment: @Groctel the snippet i posted is inside the loop. You increment inside the loop, so even if the outer loop condition was `true` it can turn `false` during the iteration. To break out of the loop inside its body you can use `break`. When `reader == line.cend()` then `*reader != ';'` is undefined (you shall not dererference an `end` iterator), hence you have to check first if `reader` is an "ok" iterator

Comment: I see that, but the intended behaviour (and how it does behave) is that after reading the last ingredient, the iterator returns to the problematic while loop (the outer one) pointing to `line.cend()`, which is why I'm baffled about this. The arbitrary characters written into the new string never contain a portion of the previous, so it should, in theory, evaluate to true. I've copied gdb output to the question because I genuinely don't understand how the logic shouldn't work. Sorry if I'm too insisting, but I'm at a big loss here...

Comment: @Groctel in the code you posted you have at the end of the outer loop `++reader` and this is undefined behaviour when `reader == line.cend();`, the output of that code could be anything, by studying it you wont learn anything new about c++, only about what your compiler does in a situtation that shouldnt occur in the first place...

Comment: Ok, I understand that I was under the false impression of iterators not being able to progress further than from the end of the iteration. Thanks!

Comment: They can't, hence the crash :P